# deploying changes after initial Grails project launch

Tags: jakarta-ee, grails, deployment, configuration

I've launched a small Grails site a few month back and now I have to deploy incremental changes to the app, most of them not involving any db changes. New tags, bug fixes in controllers, services, ect. Right now I'm simply picking through the haggis of classes and artifacts generated by running grails war SOME-WAR.war and manually dropping them into production environment. You're probably right in your sentiments at the moment and believe me this process is quite the punishment in itself.

Any suggestions on improving upon this?

- Seems like dropping an entire .war file into production every time
  something changes would be an overkill and there's the issue of
  client generated static content.
- For instance uploaded images. At the moment they're in a dir under
  images dir created when the project got initialized, they're not
  stored in db either. I thought about storing them in db for archival
  and backup purposes so they could be written back into a dir should
  something unfortunate happen, but have not gone that far yet.

Comment: swapping out a new war file is the grails deploy process.  Uploaded images need to be stored on the filesystem or in the db.  It seems like your question is more about that than deployment.

Comment: ... what about the lib or jars?

Comment: check out the dependency resolution section of the configuration doc.  This is the frameworks way to resolve JAR dependencies http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#3.7%20Dependency%20Resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, althought I would only recommend it if the changes are small, take a look at this:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Build-pre-expanded-war-file-td3337931.html

Comment: I like it. Better than hunting through the entire jar by paw anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can not incrementally update a Grails project like you can a php project or other intrepreted language based project since java is a compiled language.

You can use ant deploy scripts to automate the deployment process.  I use the remote deployment plugin for Jenkins for this task.

Comment: ... well, not exactly, I've made incremental deployments on Java web apps with ease, hence my surprise that Grails project looked like complete haggis inside the war file.

Comment: +1 Using a continuous integration tool sounds like good solution to me